# detect screen lock password entered correctly in IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, passwords, locking, device

I want to know whether it is possible to detect if the  screen lock password is entered correctly in IOS by the user while unlocking the device. Can anyone please tell me if it possible or not because I have seen some Android apps which could do that But I want to know that whether it is possible in IOS or not ?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do that. instead you can add lock to your app itself.. using some open source controller like this

[ABPadLockScreen](https://github.com/abury/ABPadLockScreen)